# How to create an IDT using LIDT I work on Intel-Atom 32bits (Assembly AT&T)

Tags: assembly, x86

How to create an IDT using LIDT 
I work on Intel-Atom 32bits (Assembly AT&T).
I am using the MocroC OSII as an OS,
i did this but it doesn,t work:

```
    Load_IDT:
push    %ebp    //save the context to swith back
mov     %esp,%ebp

movw    $256*8, -6(%esp) //256 ISR possible
movl    $IDT, -4(%esp)   //IDT is a table of 256*8bytes
lidt    -6(%esp)

pop     %ebp //Return to the calling function
ret



    static void fill_interrupt(unsigned char num, unsigned int base, unsigned short sel, unsigned char flags)
{
    unsigned short *Interrupt_Address;

    /*address = idt_ptr.base + num * 8 byte*/
    Interrupt_Address = (unsigned short *)(idt_ptr.base + num*8);

    *(Interrupt_Address) = base&0xFFFF;
    *(Interrupt_Address+1) = sel;
    *(Interrupt_Address+1) = (flags>>4)&0xFF00;
    *(Interrupt_Address+1) = (base>>16)&0xFFFF;

}


/*Change the address of idt_entries table */
fill_interrupt(ISR_Nbr,(unsigned int) isr33, 0x08, 0x8E);
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? What exactly happens and when (hang/crash/something else, inside this routine/after calling it)? What does your code do after this routine? Are interrupts enabled (EFLAGS.IF=1) prior to calling this routine? What's inside IDT?

Comment: @Alex : the IF=1, when it comes to pop %epb, it crashes !!!, and i have CPU Error (I use Eclipse:Helios)

Comment: You must keep interrupts disabled until the moment when the IDT and IDTR are properly set up. Don't set IF to 1 until you're done with IDT/IDTR (use CLI to reset it to 0). Also, make sure all segment registers (CS,DS,ES,SS,FS,GS) are loaded with valid protected mode selector values (you may load 0 if you don't use a register) prior to enabling interrupts. Returning from ISRs will typically restore them from the stack and if there was garbage before, restoring it will result in a crash.

Comment: now it doesnt crash after the pop %ebp, but whee I call int $33 (I mean the ISR 33) it crashes again

Comment: @Alex : some update: I found out that there is a BIOS on the Atom board, so I checked for the IDT and GDT "/*Read the IDTR*/sidt (idt_ptr) /*Read the GDTR*/sgdt (gdt_ptr)" and they existe, it seems like the BIOS made them. I tried to use them (see above the function fill_interrupt), after that i used "int $0x20", PFFFF the code crashed again..... :-(....any clue or remark or question ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved :), as there is a BIOS, it already built the GDT/IDT.